# Should I store users IP addresses in a separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a new website that will store IP addresses in multiple tables like *users*, *login_history*, *payments* and more.

I am wondering if I should add an `ip` column in each table and store the actual ip, or I should create a separate table named `ip_addresses` and store the ip identifier in the columns.

Method 1:

```
users:
username  |  ip
jon_snow  |  134744072
```

Method 2:

```
users:
username  |  ip
jon_snow  |  1
--
ip_addresses:
id | ip
1  | 134744072
```

Answer (score 1):

Since IP addresses will change for most of the users over time, the best place to store them is perhaps in the login_history table. This way you can associate the IP addresses with the users and their sessions.

Of course, if you want to restrict user access based on IP address and you rquire your users to use the same IP over the time, then store it in the users table.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 addresses are meaningfully formatted 32-bit integers.  IPv6 ones are meaningfully formatted again, but much larger.  Either way, you'd be creating a 1:1 mapping of dense data.  Unless you need to do it for other reasons, I would not normally choose to normalise them into another table. You're unlikely to gain speed or save space, unless your users have a very restricted set of IPs.

The used of inet(6)_aton will pack string representations, and the _ntoa version will unpack them efficiently, so you can use meaningful strings and store efficient binary versions.